# Different results between ode and using python

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I found an example online in solving [first order ode](http://ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/204/firstOrder/Modeling.htm) (2nd example) and decided to see if I could use Python to solve it.
Here's the problem statement:

> "You just won the lottery.  You put your \$5,000,000 in winnings into a fund that has a rate of return of 4%.  Each year you use \$300,000.  How much money will you have twenty years from now?"

The answer from the website is:
         $$   x   =  -2,500,000 \,e^{t/25} + 7,500,000 = 1,936,148 $$

Using Python here's my simple code:

```
#total = 5,000,000
def calc(total, years):
    for year in range(1, years):
        #total after 300,000 deduction
        total = total  - 300000
        #total after interest rate of 4%
        total = total * 1.04
    print("Final amount: " + str(total))
```

The result from python is about 1,900,822, which is about 35,325 difference. My question is, why there's a big gap? Did I program it wrong or is the method only an approximation and not an accurate answer?

Comment: Both results are wrong (but both are valid simulations), as you won't use the yearly payment at once and also not continuously at a constant rate. Also, the factor in the exponential should not be $1/25=0.04$ but $\ln(1.04)=0.03922$ to reflect that $4\%$ is the yearly interest rate. The example shows how to get a differential equation from a somewhat realistic scenario, it is to be expected that different interpretation of the scenario give slightly different simulations. You would get less difference if you refined your model to monthly steps.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and the editing. I plugged in 0.03922 into the equation with the answer = 4,900,001 which is far from what I've got. I guess I might be doing it wrong. Can you show me how it's done? Thanks.

Comment: $\dot y=p\cdot y-u$ with $y(0)=5$, $p=0.03922$, $u=0.3$ has the solution $py(t)-u=(py(0)-u)e^{pt}$ or $y(t)=y(0)+(y(0)-u/p)(e^{pt}-1)$ which gives $y(20)=1.8446915585$ (in millions). Taking $p=4\%$ for the nominal interest rate and paying out 0.3/12 and compounding monthly with rate $p/12=1/3\%$ has the formula $x_{k+1}=(1+p/12)x_k-u/12$ or $(x_n-u/p)=(1+p/12)^n(x_0-u/p)$ so that $x_n=x_0+(x_0-u/p)[(1+p/12)^n-1]$ which gives $x_{240}=1.94354478258$. Each simulation method, each assumption on the model parameters and here especially the pay-out schedule will give a slightly different result.

Comment: Just glancing at the code and difference in results, there could be one other issue with `for year in range(1, years)`, specifically `range` is inclusive of the start (`1`) __but__ exclusive of the end in that the last of `years` wont ever be looped over, eg. `[x for x in range(1, 9)]` $=$ `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`. Try `for year in range(1, years + 1)` instead and if that gets ya closer, _but not quite_, then there's likely some rounding or floating point errors getting into the mix too.